# seperate html string using componentsSeparatedByString

Tags: html, iphone, xcode, ipad, nsstring

I am using the following line in my code.But am getting "unexpected '@' in program error".I used \n and make html string to single line.but its not separating the string.how to solve this?

```
NSArray *temp1 = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>"];
```

Comment: May be </td></tr> <tr> not present. Give Str value.

Comment: </td></tr> <tr> present in my string.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str=@"<table border=1><tr><td>row 1 cell 1</td><td>row 1 cell 2</td></tr><tr><td>row 2 cell 1</td><td>row 2, cell 2</td></tr></table>";
NSArray *temp1 = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"</td></tr><tr>"];
NSLog(@"1 = %@",[temp1 objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"2 = %@",[temp1 objectAtIndex:1]);
//output
2013-06-12 15:49:02.641 PhotoPicker[5967:11303] 1 = <table border=1><tr><td>row 1        cell 1</td><td>row 1 cell 2
2013-06-12 15:49:11.544 PhotoPicker[5967:11303] 2 = <td>row 2 cell 1</td><td>row 2, cell 2</td></tr></table>
```

y that error.. can you add your string?

Comment: thanks for your info.your str is in single line.But am getting html data as reponse.so how to do?

Comment: can u add your code with response string? then it will easy to detect your problem..

Comment: @Madhumitha if i am correct you need to use this [link MWFeedParser](https://github.com/renegade78/MWFeedParser/)

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is enterKey in this text

```
@"</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>";
```

Remove Enter key and space it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `NSArray *temp1 = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"<//td><//tr><tr>"];`

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you've got some [whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) (space, cr, tab or somesuch) between your elements in that separatedBy string. Suggestions:

- Use some sort of HTML-tidying to get more predictable content before executing componentsSeparatedByString.
- Try `NSArray *temp1 = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>"];` or something similar in order to not break the separatedBy string.